# Android Kotlin: Smart cast to 'TextView' is impossible, because 'x' is a property that has open or custom getter

Tags: android, kotlin

I use `findViewById` to get references to views in a custom DialogClass outside the view hierarchy. Since I want these references throughout the dialog class, and since they are not available until the call to `setContentView`, I use lazy field initialization in the dialog class definition:

```
private val balanceView : TextView? by lazy { dialog?.findViewById(R.id.balanceTextView)}
```

Later, in a separate function that runs after the call to `setContentView`, I have two commands related to `balanceView`:

```
private fun setupBalance(){
    balanceView!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    balanceView.text = presentation.balance
}
```

I expected the second command to compile since we are ensuring `balanceView` is not null in the first command. However, the compiler underlines the second command with this message:

> Smart cast to 'TextView' is impossible, because 'balanceView' is a property that has open or custom getter

I was wondering how to interpret this message - to my knowledge the `lazy` keyword doesn't make a variable open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of a property delegate like `lazy` means it has a custom getter. A custom getter prevents the compiler from being able to ensure that the value returned by the property will be the same in your two consecutive calls, so it cannot smart-cast.

Since `balanceView` is nullable, you shouldn't be using `!!` either, or your app will crash when `balanceView` is null. The correct way to write your function (if you don't know if `balanceView` is currently null) would be like this:

```
private fun setupBalance(){
    balanceView?.apply {
        visibility = View.VISIBLE
        text = presentation.balance
    }
}
```

If there's no chance of it being null, don't use a nullable property, and then you won't have to worry about null-safe calls and smart-casting. But  you seem to also have a nullable `dialog` that it is dependent on. I don't know what's going on higher-up-stream, so I can't help with that.